# Have numeric data to categorical data in R

Tags: r

I have survey data called on which responses participant responses.

I have my data in this format 4 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3

Or, in `dput` format:

```
c(4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3)
```

but I want to categorize them as

```
strongly disagree = 1 
disagree = 2 
agree = 3 
strongly agree = 4
```

so that I can have different colors when I do a histogram.

I tried using doing this

```
datatat = survey$Q1A 
catsurvey <- cut(datatat, breaks =c(0,2,3,4),  labels=c("Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree"))    
hist(datatat , main="Distribution of Player Ratings", xlab="Responses", border = "black" ,col = c("blue", "red", "green"))
```

Comment: A histogram is generally used for showing the distribution of a continuous variable. It seems like what you're trying to set up is actually a bar chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. I gave another name to the data you have posted, since I didn't want to create a dataframe.

```
x <- scan(text = '4 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3')
labs <- c('strongly disagree',
          'disagree',
          'agree',
          'strongly agree')

datatat <- factor(x, levels = 1:4, labels = labs)
tbl <- table(datatat)

barplot(tbl[tbl != 0],
     main = "Distribution of Player Ratings", 
     xlab = "Responses", 
     border = "black", col = c("blue", "red", "green"))
```

[image]